# Filter and count array in angular.js controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an array of objects in my Angular app and each has a "ready" field, which is a timestamp. I want to count the number of objects where the ready timestamp is earlier than the current time. How would I do this?

I have:

```
$scope.getDatetime = new Date();
$scope.numberReady = $filter('filter')($scope.array, {ready <  $scope.getDatetime}).length;
```

Obviously I can't use `ready < $scope.getDatetime`, but that, logically speaking, is what I want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pure ES5 filter method, no need of Angular here:

```
$scope.getDatetime = new Date();
$scope.numberReady = $scope.array.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.ready < $scope.getDatetime;
}).length;
```

... although you could use Angular filter here too:

```
$scope.getDatetime = new Date();
$scope.numberReady = $filter('filter')($scope.array, function(obj) {
    return obj.ready <  $scope.getDatetime;
}).length;
```

but since it's just a wrapper around native thing, this is not ideal in this case.

Comment: Thanks, this works. I'm actually having a problem comparing the datetimes though because new date() when printed to the console gives me "Sun Aug 02 2015 13:11:45 GMT+0300 (EEST)", but the datimes coming from my api are in the format "2015-07-26T21:41:01.938+03:00". Any idea how to make these comparable?